# Open activity monitor minimized on startup

Tags: macos, dock, activity-monitor

I sometimes like to have Activity Monitor running in the dock (to see CPU usage chart in the icon at a glance).

I didn't use it for some time though, but with a new mac I bought (El Capitan) I thought I'd activate it again.

Now I can have it start automatically but I always have to minimize the Activity Monitor window after login.

I *think* in the past6 I had set it with that option (to autostart at login  via right-click on the dock icon) so that it started minimized but I can't seem to remember how.

Am I remembering wrong or missing an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this not work?

First right-click on Activity Monitor and go **Options > Open at Login**.

Next, open **System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items** and tick **Hide**.

Comment: Yay. That sounds like what I was missing (I thought I knew there was an option somewhere, but was looking inside Activity Monitor).  I'll try tomorrow and am sure it will work (will give you correct answer then).

Comment: Correct.  This must get a reward for the best hidden option of all times.

Comment: (macOS 10.13) For this the main answer to work you have to make sure you **quit** any manually started Activity Monitors before you logout otherwise the session saving will cause the window to appear when you next log in. An alternative is to simply hide the Activity Monitor window (e.g. via ⌘H) before you log out/shutdown and let the session save that state.

Comment: Thanks for this! It should just be an extra Option in the Activity Monitor's Dock Options menu.  Just request Apple to do this by using Activity Monitor's "Send Feedback" option in its Help menu.  Must be so easy to add.

Comment: It seems in macOS Ventura the "Hide" option in the settings is gone. How do I do this in Ventura?